# What is the best way to fill narrow gaps between floor and skirting boards

Tags: flooring, gap, skirting

I have narrow gaps between the floor (Amtico) and the skirting boards (not over 1.5/2 mm) that I would like to fill but I'm not sure what to use. The floor is quite elastic so ideally I'd need something that sticks and that is also flexible and doesn't crumble. Being able to paint over it is a bonus, but the main goal is to fill those gaps. What's the best product that I could get in the UK to get the job done?

[image]

Comment: How about a picture so we can see what you see.

Comment: @JACK thanks, I've added a photo

Comment: it would actually look worse (wobbly/wavy) if you had no straight shadow line.

Answer (score 2):

If skirting board by itself isn't sufficient then you can add a length of quarter round as well.

[image]

Comment: the picture shows cove, but you recommend 1/4 round?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a floating laminate floor it really should  be left alone. Scribing and cutting the baseboard (skirting) would have been best, but to caulk the gap, which is the other alternative would bond the flooring to a degree to the flooring and not allow it to move as it needs.
The shoe mold is an idea that is used but has is drawbacks, it is typically nailed at an angle into the floor, in the case of floating floor, it would be in essence, nailing the flooring in place. If it is nailed only into the skirting then its holding power is minimized, and possibly will leave the same gap that you are holding objection too. Besides in my opinion, adding another piece of molding will detract rather add to the look.

Now, if it is solid floor, or glue down, and not a floating laminate, I would a good grade of latex caulk to caulk it, but be very careful about the cleaning off of the excess.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; as mentioned in the OP the flooring is Amtico (vinyl)

Comment: I take it all Amtico is vinyl? In the States, the makers produce many varieties.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Amtico is just vinyl: https://www.amtico.com/

Comment: Then if it is not glued down, which some vinyl floor can be, it is a floating floor and needs to move due to various changes. When the floor was laid it was required to keep a minimum gap of say 5-8mm at all edges? If so, that is the gap required by the maker to allow for movement.

Comment: I think the gaps are not meant to be there because they are not all around the perimeter of each room, but just in some places. I believe they have been created by the building still settling (it's a new build flat).

Comment: Yes that is correct. The lumber itself due to humidity changes in the wood will create small dips here and there in the floor like you have there. If it is a concrete floor, the same thing will occur, because it is nearly impossible to get concrete perfectly flat.